# How do you tell what address in memory you are storing a variable to in ASM?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm

I am very new to ASM and I want to watch how the memory changes as I go through my code in debug mode (with breakpoints). The problem is I have no clue as to where my variables are stored in memory. I've been searching through it for a while now for the right location, but memory is huge and I have had no luck. :)

If someone could tell me the address where my EAX values are stored that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Here is the ASM code:

[image: ASM Code]

Comment: Would help if we knew what environment you are using. What Assembler (I suspect MASM), and what debugger (screenshot suggests it might be Visual Studio?)?

Comment: Yes sir I am using Visual Studios 13. Also to note: I know how to open the memory window, I just don't know where my values are stored there.

Comment: I don't have VS in front of me but there is a way of seeing your assembly source code interspersed with the actual machine instructions (which would include their physical memory addresses). Doesn't the memory window allow you to specify actual names of variables (rather than just their physical addresses)

Comment: In this case, number and number are the addresses of 32-bit variables. If you want to refer to those addresses, you can use their names.  If you want to know what their literal values are, run in a debugger and examine them, but generally as a programmer you don’t need that information.

Comment: @Lorehead the OP is in the VS debugger in the screenshot. The breakpoints are set along the left hand side.

Comment: I think you want to have Visual Studio show you the disassembly window maybe?

Comment: Ah.  Should be able to examine number and number2 by name, then.

Comment: So for example, if I type "number" into the memory window search bar, it will bring me to that variables location (address)?

Comment: Yes, It should work that way

Comment: They’re likely to be turned into offsets, but yes.

Comment: On a side note. Once you hit a break point in your code you can see the disassembly of the current code by hitting CONTROL-ALT-D. You would then see your source code and the corresponding machine instructions displayed with their addresses.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Use cut & paste to include your code as text into your post. Be sure to format the inserted text as code by selecting it and using pressing the {} button.

Comment: @RossRidge Copy and paste is preferable, then I don't need to have them ask me why their code disappeared ;-)

Comment: I used screenshot so you could also see the breakpoints. Not sure if they are helpful at all in solving the problem, though.

Comment: Also, thanks for the help :)